# Oracle Stored Procedure with out parameter using Nhibernate

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, stored-procedures

How can I access the value of an out parameter of an oracle stored procedure in the .net code - Oracle stored procedure being called via Nhibernate?

Sample working code would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the latest version of NHibernate (2.1.2).

```
<sql-query name="ReturnSomethig" callable="true">
   <return class="Somethig" />
   { call ReturnSomethig(:someParameter) }
</sql-query>
```

The Oracle Stored Procedure need to has the first parameter as a out sys_refcursor parameter.

And you can call the named query like that:

```
IQuery query = currentSession.GetNamedQuery("ReturnSomethig");
query.SetInt64("someParameter", someParameter);
var somethig = query.List<Somethig>();
```

And it will work.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work.  When I downloaded the source I actually had to make several changes utilizing this post (https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=999056).  This was with the 2.1.2 release also.

Comment: We didn't use the refcursor for our problem at that time, however, I feel this would have been the solution to my question. Hence, accepting it. And *do refer* to the link by Blake above.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the 2.1.2 libraries without much luck.  I had to actually make some modifications to the library based on [this article](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=999056).  If you go this route, you'll want to make sure you are using the Oracle.DataAccess dll since it won't work with System.DataAccess.OracleClient dll.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst looking into getting out parameters from NHibernate I found various links suggesting that to get a stored proc out parameter value (rather than using a refcursor) you need to construct the command in code rather than using the XML mappings file.

But I found difficulty finding a complete working example online. It's not a beautiful solution, but I post in case it helps someone.

1. Example Oracle stored proc:

   ```
   create or replace PACKAGE BODY MY_PACKAGE AS

     PROCEDURE add_one
     (
       p_out out number,
       p_in in number
     ) AS
     BEGIN
       select p_in + 1 into p_out from dual;
     END add_one;

   END MY_PACKAGE;
   ```
2. Example C# code, where `sessionFactory` is an NHibernate `ISessionFactory`:

   ```
   using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
   using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
   {
       var command = session.Connection.CreateCommand();
       command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       command.CommandText = "MY_PACKAGE.add_one";

       var parmOut = command.CreateParameter();
       parmOut.ParameterName = "p_out";
       parmOut.DbType = DbType.Decimal;
       parmOut.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
       command.Parameters.Add(parmOut);

       var parmIn = command.CreateParameter();
       parmIn.ParameterName = "p_in";
       parmIn.DbType = DbType.Decimal;
       parmIn.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
       parmIn.Value = 67;
       command.Parameters.Add(parmIn);

       transaction.Enlist(command);
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();

       int sixtyEight = (int) (decimal) parmOut.Value;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

See **[this comment](http://nhjira.koah.net/browse/NH-847?focusedCommentId=18790#action_18790)** by Richard Brown. Some sample code can be found **[here](http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate.Test/SqlTest/Custom/Oracle/)**.
Unfortunately I can't test it so I don't know whether it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

A belated reply.

For oracle, out parameter is not supported by nHibernate unless it is a cursor. If you just want a scalar value, a work around is to wrap your stored procedure with an oracle function.

Then you can do this

```
  <sql-query name="TestOracleFunction" callable="true">
    <return-scalar column="MyOutputValue" type="String" />
    <![CDATA[
    select MyOracleFunction as MyOutputValue from dual
  ]]>
  </sql-query>
```

This works!