# Runtime Error - Named query not known - Nibernate, Oracle, C#

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, runtime-error

I have looked and many examples and Questions/Answers here on Stackoverflow and elsewhere. I do not understand why my C# does not see the Oracle SP. Any help would be appreciated.

Basic goal -

I have a Oracle SP (shown below) which returns a cursor in return parameter #1, and is given two string parameters in #2, and #3.

I call the SP from C# attempting to place the returning Resultset into a C# List of Class ExtractCoastalSurvey1SP. (shown below)

My code blows up on the Nhibernate command GetNamedQuery.

Oracle SP, NHibernate Mapping XML File, NHibernate Mapping Code, Calling Code and Runtime Error Dump all below.

If you need any more info, let me know - sblalock  at the gmail.com.

Thanks for the Help. Solve this and be elevated to God status in my eyes! Cheers and have a Blessed Day!

M. Scott Blalock

### Runtime Error

```
Named query not known: PROC_MASSANDABUNDANCE Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: NHibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: PROC_MASSANDABUNDANCE

Source Error:

Line 7257:////query.SetParameter("SPECIESCODE_IN", "6186020202");
Line 7258: Line 7259: IQuery query = Session.GetNamedQuery("PROC_MASSANDABUNDANCE"); Line 7260: query.SetParameter("PROJECTCODE_IN", "P94"); Line 7261: query.SetParameter("SPECIESCODE_IN", "6186020202");

Source File: C:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SEAMAP\SEAMAP\SEAMAP\Service\DBRepository.cs Line: 7259

Stack Trace:

[MappingException: Named query not known: PROC_MASSANDABUNDANCE] NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetNamedQuery(String queryName) +509 SEAMAP.Services.DBRepository.ExtractCoastalSurvey1Collection(String[] _AreaArray, String _LatitudeRangeBegin, String _LatitudeRangeEnd, String _YearRangeBegin, String _YearRangeEnd, String _Season, String _State, String _DepthZone, String[] _SelectedMonthArray, String[] _SelectedYearArray, String[] _SelectedScientificNamesArray, String[] _SelectedCommonNamesArray, String[] _SelectedACCSPGridArray) in C:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SEAMAP\SEAMAP\SEAMAP\Service\DBRepository.cs:7259 SEAMAP.Controllers.ReportsController.ExtractCoastalSurvey(ExtractCoastalSurveyParameters _model) in C:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SEAMAP\SEAMAP\SEAMAP\Controllers\ReportsController.cs:277 lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +140 System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17 System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary2 parameters) +178 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary2 parameters) +24 System.Web.Mvc.<>c_DisplayClassd.b_a() +52 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func1 continuation) +254 System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassf.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__c() +19 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary2 parameters) +192 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +314 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +105 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +39 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +7 System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4() +34 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass81.b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +59 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +7 System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8699438 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

### From ORACLE

```
PROCEDURE PROC_MASSANDABUNDANCE 
(p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,PROJECTCODE_IN IN VARCHAR2, SPECIESCODE_IN IN VARCHAR2) AS 

BEGIN

OPEN p_recordset FOR

SELECT * FROM TABLE;

END PROC_MASSANDABUNDANCE;
```

### Mappings.HMB.XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="SEAMAP" assembly="SEAMAP" >


  <sql-query name="PROC_MASSANDABUNDANCE" Callable="true">
     <query-param name="PROJECTCODE_IN" type="string" />
     <query-param name="SPECIESCODE_IN" type="string" />

    <return class="SEAMAP.Models.ExtractCoastalSurvey1SP" />

    { call PROC_MASSANDABUNDANCE(:PROJECTCODE_IN :SPECIESCODE_IN) } 

  </sql-query>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

### C# Code

### Mapping Code

```
    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
               .Database(OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10
               .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey(connString))
               .ShowSql())
               .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "web"))
               .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Project>())
               .Mappings(m => m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Project>())
               .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

### Calling Code

```
                    IQuery query = Session.GetNamedQuery("PROC_MASSANDABUNDANCE");
                    query.SetParameter("PROJECTCODE_IN", "P94");
                    query.SetParameter("SPECIESCODE_IN", "6186020202");

                    return query.List<ExtractCoastalSurvey1SP>();
```

Comment: Where do you set your OUT parameter?  Its not the same as a function that returns a value.

Comment: btw: search for nhibernate OUT parameter got me this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804879/oracle-stored-procedure-with-out-parameter-using-nhibernate

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you append the schema name to the procedure?  As in [schema].[procedure].

For my packaged code in C# applications I always put the cursor last but this is probably not mandatory for fluent-nhibernate